# Scalatest assume database is available in each test

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest, preconditions

Many of my tests are dependent on the database. I use the following to check the connection before running the test case:

```
assume(database.isAvailable, "Database is down")
```

When I add it to each test case, the correct `!!! CANCELED !!!` with the correct message is displayed in the output.

When I add it to the `beforeEach` method:

```
override def beforeEach() = {
  assume(database.isAvailable, "Database is down")
}
```

all I can see is just `Exception encountered when attempting to run a suite with class name` and `*** ABORTED ***` (on the line with the `assume` call).

Do I really need to add this assumption to each testcase?

Comment: Not really an answer, but wouldn't you be better off by mocking the db rather than having it really there?

Comment: Yeah, I have two types of tests: those with database mock and the second type (integration tests) which I want to do this way

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is something intended. See

http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures

> Mix in a before-and-after trait when you want an aborted suite, not a
>   failed test, if the fixture code fails.

On that same page there are other alternatives. Possibly worths a look `withFixture`